# Duda con la lógica de programación de un Decimal a Binario JS

Tags: javascript, while, lógica

Hace unos días he comenzado a estudiar Js de manera independiente y me encontré con un ejercicio que pide transformar de Binario a Decimal. Ya resolví el ejercicio con la opción **toString** y me gustaría practicarlo de manera lógica para mejorar un poco mis habilidades. Ya mas o menos tengo la lógica pero cuando pongo la condición en el while no logro hacer que se vuelve a repetir la condición pero ahora ya con el nuevo numero además al llegar a cero se sigue ejecutando, me gustaría poder realizar algo similar.

9/2 = 4 Residuo: 1

4/2 = 2 Residuo: 0

2/2 = 1 Residuo: 0

1/2 = 0 Residuo: 1

```js
const convertidorBinario = (num)=>{
    let almacenador = []
    while (num!==0){
        let div = (num/2)
        let residuo = parseInt(num%2)
        div = num;
        console.log(`El Div es: ${div} y el Residuo:${residuo}`);
        almacenador.push(residuo);
    }
    return almacenador
}
convertidorBinario(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que la variable `num` nunca varia, te olvidaste actualizarla.

```js
const convertidorBinario = (num)=>{
    let almacenador = []
    while (num!==0){
        let residuo = parseInt(num%2)
        num = Math.floor(num/2);
        almacenador.push(residuo);
        console.log(`El Div es: ${num} y el Residuo:${residuo}`);
    }
    return almacenador
}
convertidorBinario(9);
```

Comment: Efectivamente, agradezco tu atención y doy por cerrada la pregunta.

Comment: @EdgarOcampo acepta la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Código con explicación de cambios en los comentarios:

```js
const convertidorBinario = (num)=>{
    let almacenador = []
    while (num!==0){
        // 1. Redondear al entero inferior
        // para que div no sea un número decimal
        let div = Math.floor(num / 2)
        let residuo = parseInt(num%2)
        // 2. Ahora num será igual a div, si no es así
        // se produce un bucle infinito
        num = div;
        console.log(`El Div es: ${div} y el Residuo:${residuo}`);
        almacenador.push(residuo);
    }
    return almacenador
}
convertidorBinario(5);
```